# Set MUI Theme for Specific React Page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

We are using MUI with our React site and currently have light & dark themes. I would like to force the light theme on a specific page (log in). For some reason, I cannot seem to find a solution anywhere online. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Got it - see below

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';

const loginTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: '#303030',
      paper: '#424242'
    },
  },
});

<ThemeProvider theme={loginTheme}>
   wrap the content you want to use the above theme
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: Could you please add more explanations to your answer?